# Textblock text bind in controltemplate question

Tags: silverlight, bind, controltemplate, textblock

I'm creating my own control, I'm wondering the best way to bind the textblock text property below, I have the contentpresenter set to bind to content, how can I set the textblock text value?

```
<Style TargetType="ctrl:Selection">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lavender" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ctrl:Selection">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="black" RadiusX="16" RadiusY="16" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="How do i bind this?" x:Name="HeaderText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" x:Name="BodyContent" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

public class Selection : ContentControl {
    public Selection() {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Selection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a property in your control class, something like this...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(Selection), new PropertyMetadata(""));

public string Text {
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
```